# How to mention valid users in an Adaptive Card in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

The experience I had is to display "blahblah@example.com" as literal texts.

(The email address actually sent was valid. The above dummy email address is just for credentials' concern.)

Here is the JSON sent as a Channel message

```
{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "size": "medium",
                        "text": "<at>blahblah@example.com</at> Hello World",
                        "wrap": false,
                        "type": "TextBlock"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "actions": []
    }
}
```

Better to use my own bot, instead of the Flow[bot].

Answer (score 0):

@Leon Currently, it is not possible to at-mention a user in an Adaptive card. You could [mention in a text message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#constructing-mentions) but not in card. This is something we are working on but we do not have an ETA to share with you.

Comment: Since 2020, there seems to be support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards